# Different image on each click

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

In my application, I have 4 images. I want to show diffrent images on each click. How to show different images on each click?

Here my code for single image:

```
-(void)removeImageView
{   
    rightongbanner.image=Nil;
}

-(void)alertshow
{
    rightongbanner.image=[UIImage  imageNamed:@"correct.png"];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(removeImageView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [aplayer play];
}
```

In `rightongbanner.image`, I want to show img1 on first click and img2 on second click. How can I do this?

Comment: you can increment a counter on each click and based on that you can show images on uiimageview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this,

in `.h`

```
int a;
```

in `.m`

```
-(void)loadView  {
    a=0;
}

-(void)alertshow
{
   if((a%4)==0)
       rightongbanner.image=[UIImage  imageNamed:@"correct1.png"];
   if((a%4)==1)
       rightongbanner.image=[UIImage  imageNamed:@"correct2.png"];
   if((a%4)==2)
       rightongbanner.image=[UIImage  imageNamed:@"correct3.png"];
   if((a%4)==3)
       rightongbanner.image=[UIImage  imageNamed:@"correct4.png"];

  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(removeImageView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
     [aplayer play];
  a++;
}
```